# Plotting values in the multiple of 100's on the y axis

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I want to plot values in the multiple of hundreds on the Y axis but the values after calculations comes out to be different for example: 6233,12466,18699... how can I make them like 6000,12000,18000... 
This is just one data.

I want to keep the y values on Y axis to be in the multiple of 100.

The formula I am using to calculate the points is

```
m_oLineChart.ChartArea.AxisY.UnitMajor = Math.Round((m_oLineChart.ChartArea.AxisY.Max - m_oLineChart.ChartArea.AxisY.Min) / 5);
```

Comment: The numbers on the Axis are Labels that are spaced in Intervals as fit. Reaza's answer ought to help. __Your code doesn't even compile with a MSChart !!__

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show y-axis labels with a specific interval, you can use [`Interval`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.axis.interval(v=vs.110).aspx) property of [`AxisY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.chartarea.axisy(v=vs.110).aspx).

**Example**

```
void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 6000;
    var random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(random.Next(6000, 20000));
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It would be great if you let me know what's wrong with the answer.

Comment: To make sure this work he might need to also set the Minimum; to further influens the Labels he might want to use the IntervalOffset.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to round the actual values to nearest hundred use the following

```
Math.Round(18699d / 100d, 0) * 100; // = 18600
```

To nearest thousand

```
Math.Round(18699d / 1000d, 0) * 1000; // = 18000
```